# Picasso images are not loading in markers Android Now the problem is that the Picasso is not loading the images properly

Tags: java, android, kotlin, picasso

**Picasso images are not loading in markers Android Now the problem is that the Picasso is not loading the images properly.**

```
fun loadRoundedImage(imgProgram: AppCompatImageView, image: String, defaultImage: Int = 0) {

    if (image.isEmpty()) {
        Picasso.get()
            .load(defaultImage)
            .placeholder(defaultImage)
            .error(defaultImage)
            .into(imgProgram)

    } else {
        Picasso.get()
            .load(image)
            .placeholder(defaultImage)
            .error(defaultImage)
            .into(imgProgram)
    }
}
```

Comment: Share some code for the related question.

Comment: Share your code here

Comment: Check whether your image is empty or not. May be you first if condition is working all the time.

Comment: I checked it , if image is empty picassi is loading default image .

Comment: Your question is not clear, please clarify. Which image you want to load if `URL` is empty?

Comment: I load some bitmap images ! , but  first time they are not loading , but for the others time all of images are loading !